# How Make a Hierarchical Selection with SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, selection, hierarchical

I have a problem in creating a SQL Query as follows :

I Have 2 Tables with following Specification and data:

http://dc699.4shared.com/img/lgtP3N_4ce/s3/144c7252ff8/SQL1.jpg

I want to create a SQL Select Query to return for me a Hierarchical Model Like this :

For example if the SID is 3 it should return for me this :

http://dc699.4shared.com/img/8UufpK2-ce/s3/144c7255af0/SQL2.jpg

Because the Num 3 in structure table related to data 7,8,9 and 9 is related to 10,11(Note that No 9 is related to 3 or in other words 9 is subset of 3)

Can anyone help me to create this Query? I have try for 2 weeks but I failed :(

Thanks so much

Comment: what will be the output if you select SID as 1 or 2?

Comment: if it is 2 it should be 2,5,6 or if it is 1 it should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 because of it's relations

Answer (score 0):

Untested answer, and it does not include the root member for readability and because your examples in the question and comments are inconsistent. This should get you going.

I made the query starting with root = 1

```
WITH members (id)
AS
(SELECT MID as id FROM structure WHERE SID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT     MID as id 
FROM       members 
INNER JOIN structure ON (members.id = structure.SID)
)
SELECT members.ID FROM members;
```

members is the intermediary table created by the CTE (WITH...)

[**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7d67/2)

Comment: Dear koriander thanks for your answer but can you tell me these parameter such as hierarchy , members is related to which table? because I have 2 tables Structure & Personels and i can not endrestand these name . when I type these code in sql give me errors that say these are not recognized

Comment: Dear koriander thanks for your answer but when I run query it give me error , I have add ; in end of line 1 but not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also try an Rank solution like this one

```
WITH Personel_Structure AS
```

(
SELECT [SID],MID, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [SID] ORDER BY MID ASC) AS POS
FROM Structure
WHERE [SID] = 3
)
SELECT [SID],MID
FROM Personel_Structure
ORDER BY POS ASC

I have script this against the structure table if you need to do a join to the personel table that should be easy from here.  Just join the the tables in the CTE.

Comment: Dear Nathan thanks for your answer but when I run query it give me error in line 1 and tell have error near WITH syntax

Comment: Hi This works fine for me can you show me how you've written your script. it should be as this  WITH Personel_Structure AS
( 
 SELECT [SID],MID, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY [SID] ORDER BY MID ASC) AS POS FROM Structure WHERE [SID] = 3 
)
 SELECT [SID],MID FROM Personel_Structure ORDER BY POS ASC

Comment: I have also tested it at this link and it worked ok there http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7d67/3 can you have a look and let me know